# Auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts

Tags: fonts, moderncv, vscode, latex-workshop

I'm using `moderncv` package
Working inside VSCode's LaTeX Workshop extension
At compilation it gives:

```
[1{/home/kein/.texlive2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
/home/kein/Documents/cv/AEP/cvshka.tex:54: pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto   expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                              \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...
l.54 ...
```

My preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,color,finish,russian]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{comment}
\recomputelengths
```

I've runned `updmap -sys`, but still getting the same issue

The whole document can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/96bYCbA8)

Comment: don't link to external site, such links will be dead in the future and then your question will be incomplete and useless for others. Add `\makeatletter\disable@package@load{microtype}{}\makeatother` before \documentclass, and then look at the end of the log-file which fonts are used, and which one are still pk-fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `<larm1200.600pk> <larm1728.600pk>{fa5free1.enc} <larm1095.600pk>{fa5free2.enc} <larm2074.600pk> <larm3583.600pk><FontAwesome5Free-Regular.pfb><FontAwesome5Free-Solid.pfb>`

Comment: install the cm-super fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have it installed